# sqlserver on linux Azure performance

Tags: sql-server, linux, azure

Im new to sqlserver, we have a sqlserver running on linux and we are encountering performance issues
i see sometimes SUSPENDED on the queries / selects etc

If i change the max degree of parallelism                     0       32767            0           0
would it help?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15
any other comments would be great

Answer (score 1):

a query gets suspended when it is requesting access to a resource that is currently not available. This can be a logical resource like a locked row or a physical resource like a memory data page, or some logical cpus. The query starts running again, once the resource becomes available.

Try to focus on identify the cause of your issue.
Try to identify the query that is suspended and then look into the wait stats affecting that query. Here you will find what is blocking that query. Which resource it is wainting for. Maybe there is no enough memory or cpu or the query is waiting for something else.

Then you can evaluate a solution.